# Visual Prolog: Перебор элементов нескольких списков

Tags: list, prolog

Пишу программу составления кроссворда на Visual Prolog. Застряла на моменте получения всех возможных наборов элементов 4 листов. Все 4 списка разной длины. Необходимо получать набор из 4 элементов, по одному из каждого списка и в дальнейшем осуществлять необходимую мне проверку другим предикатом. Так нужно перебрать все комбинации этих листов.

Например, имеем 3 списка и надо получить наборы по 3 эл-та:
    [1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8]:

```
1, 4, 6;
1, 4, 7;
1, 4, 8;
1, 5, 6;
1, 5, 7;
1, 5, 8;
2, 4, 6;
```

и т.д.

Перебор элементов одного списка дело не трудное, но как сделать перебор по 4 спискам я не знаю. Может как-то с помощью встроенных предикатов list::?
Помогите пожалуйста. Может есть какие-то идеи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привожу решение на "классическом Прологе" с помощью предиката `member/2`(в *Visual Prolog*, насколько я знаю, есть метод `isMember()`, делающий то же самое).

```
    iterate_4(List1,List2,List3,List4,Goal) :-
        member(E1, List1),
        member(E2, List2),
        member(E3, List3),
        member(E4, List4),
        once(callN(Goal, E1, E2, E3, E4)),
        fail.

    iterate_4(_,_,_,_,_).
```

`member/2` работает для случая "1й параметр-несвязанная переменная, 2й параметр- связанная переменная", (один из 4х списков), и имеет `n` решений, где `n` длина этого списка.

`fail` генерирует возврат и, таким образом, все `member/2`-цели начинают выдавать все решения из списков, начиная c `member(Е4, List4)`, и, заканчивая `member(Е1, List1)`.

Исчерпав все комбинации, *Пролог* переходит ко 2-му предложению и успешно завершает вычисления.

Цель `once(callN(Goal, E1, E2, E3, E4)),` этого просто Ваш код для обработки набора из 4х элементов "для проверки другим предикатом".